# .NEt Async CTP equivalent in java

Tags: java, .net, asynchronous, async-ctp

In there anything in java that is similar to the async ctp of .NET? If not, what are closest options to do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing really like it at the moment at the language level, but I think the closest thing you'll find is the [Fork/Join Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html).